# Synchronize 2 SharePoint Libraries on Different Servers

Tags: sharepoint-2010, shared-libraries

I need to copy or synchronize 2 libraries between 2 different servers. Here are more details:
1- I have an InfoPath form that is submitted to a document library, Lib #1.
2- The InfoPath form is published as a content type and Lib #1 is configured to deal with this content type.
3- The users will have the ability to add new items to Lib #1.
4- At the end of each day, or may be every hour or so, I need to copy the newly created items or sync Lib #1 with another library on a different server.
5- The content type will be available in both servers.

I am new to SharePoint so I appreciate if you can show me some hints on how to achieve that.

**Clarification**
I don't know which route to take, I am thinking of utilizing any of these (if possible):
1- Replicating Database: Use replication to copy data from one SharePoint database to the other
2- File System: I am not sure if the forms are saved in file system but if they are, I could copy the forms from one server to another.
3- Programatically: I am reading about SharePoint server events. I can program against the List Item Added event and try to copy the item from one server to anther.
4- Built in: May be there is a built in tool that I am not aware of that can help me copy items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to do that ? If the target is entirely different server, forms won't open from there unless you relink the documents and you have same form template deployed on that server.

To do this job, you have two options:

1. Realtime - Use `ItemAdded` event handler, to copy the item to target as soon as it is created.
2. Timer Job - You can create a timer job which will run as per some schedule and copy the items from one library to other.

Reject the DB and file system approach. Accessing DB directly is not supported. And these are not stored on filesystems. SharePoint API is only way. You can use either in Event handler or timer job.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by relink documents. The target is to copy the saved forms to an entirely different server and open them there. I am planning to deploy the same InfoPath form on both servers and create identical libraries. Will that be enough?

Comment: I will mark this as an answer because it showed me the correct way to do it. however I am still experimenting with the item added event.

Comment: It will not work unless you relink, because the form will contain path to the xsn file on old server. You can update it by process called relinking...

Comment: Please see [about relinking](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/42579/8319). I'm late but might be helpful to others searching for answers